# Java - URL connection does not seem to work

Tags: java, url, urlconnection

```
public void enviarCadena(String s){
    s="http://192.168.1.7:36000/"+s;

    try {
        url = new URL(s);
        conexion = url.openConnection();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){

    }

}
```

I wrote this code. If I go to the URL in the browser, the browser sends the data to the server, but not when I execute my method in Java. The program does not throw an exception, all goes fine, but the server does not receive anything. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the maximun size to POST is aprox 8MG, so not can send a big chain in one time, but i cuted and send in diferents times and it worked. I resolved with a read petition to open and comprove the send in the server. Thanks Glorfindel for your atempt for help me

Answer (score 3):

[`openConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()) will **not** perform the call to the server. To do this, you need the [`connect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect()) method:

```
conexion.connect();
```

Comment: I have to write just like this? url = new URL(s); conexion = url.openConnection(); conexion.connect(); I try then, butnot found. Thanks

Comment: *Sí* - what do you mean by 'not found'?

Comment: I need this to send params to a server, but doesn't arrive to server. The conexion is OK, but not write into the server